# cannot populate path because it is not in your Schema

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, backend, mongoose-populate

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const imageUploadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: "true",
  },
  image: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "influencerimg",
  }],
});
exports.imageUpload = mongoose.model("image-upload", imageUploadSchema);

//image Model
    const ImgSchema = new Schema({    
    bio:String,
    image:String,   
});
exports.influencerimg = mongoose.model('influencerimg', ImgSchema);

//my Controller
const model = require("../model/userUpload");
const imageUpload = model.imageUpload;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

exports.uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
  const { user, image } = req.body;
  try {    
    const alreadyExist = await imageUpload.findOne({ user })
    console.log(alreadyExist,'alreadyExist')  
    if (alreadyExist) {
      const updateimgId = await imageUpload.findOneAndUpdate({ user }, {
        $push:{image}
      })
      if (updateimgId) {
        return res.status(200).json({success:1,message:'image ID Iploaded Successfully'})
      }
    } else {
      const createNewById = new imageUpload({ user, image });
      await createNewById.save();
      return res.send({ code: 200, message: "Image added successfully" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
};

exports.getImage = async (req, res) => {                                                                    
  // const userId = req.params._id;
  // const data = await imageUpload.findById({ user:userId }).populate('influencerimg')
  const data = await imageUpload.findOne({ user: req.params.user }).populate({ path: 'influencerimg', select: 'image', options: { strictPopulate: false } })  
  if (data) {
    return res.status(200).json({message:'Data fetced Successfully',data:data})
  } else {
    return res.status(500).json({message:'Data not Found'})
  }
}
```

//Why am i getting StrictPopulateError: Cannot populate path `influencerimg` because it is not in your schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override.
at getModelsMapForPopulate (E:\React-Live\socialinfluencer\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\populate\getModelsMapForPopulate.js:49:12)....help me out Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You want to populate the `imageUpload`'s `image` field, so the populate path is `image`, **not** `influencerimg`.

E.g.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);

const imageUploadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'influencerimg' }],
});
const ImageUpload = mongoose.model('image-upload', imageUploadSchema);

const ImgSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    bio: String,
    image: String,
});
const Influencerimg = mongoose.model('influencerimg', ImgSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        // seed
        const [img1, img2] = await Influencerimg.create([
            { bio: 'a', image: 'img-a' },
            { bio: 'b', image: 'img-b' },
        ]);
        const imageUpload = new ImageUpload();
        // @ts-ignore
        imageUpload.image.push(img1, img2);
        await imageUpload.save();

        // test
        const r = await ImageUpload.findOne({ _id: imageUpload._id }).populate({ path: 'image', select: 'image' });
        console.log(r?.toObject());
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Debug logs:

```
Mongoose: influencerimgs.insertOne({ bio: 'a', image: 'img-a', _id: ObjectId("649e88ae9e6ef39cf8b3a10b"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: influencerimgs.insertOne({ bio: 'b', image: 'img-b', _id: ObjectId("649e88ae9e6ef39cf8b3a10c"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: image-uploads.insertOne({ image: [ ObjectId("649e88ae9e6ef39cf8b3a10b"), ObjectId("649e88ae9e6ef39cf8b3a10c") ], _id: ObjectId("649e88ae9e6ef39cf8b3a10f"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: image-uploads.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("649e88ae9e6ef39cf8b3a10f") }, {})
Mongoose: influencerimgs.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("649e88ae9e6ef39cf8b3a10b"), ObjectId("649e88ae9e6ef39cf8b3a10c") ], [Symbol(mongoose#trustedSymbol)]: true }}, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, projection: { image: 1 }})
{
  _id: new ObjectId("649e88ae9e6ef39cf8b3a10f"),
  image: [
    { _id: new ObjectId("649e88ae9e6ef39cf8b3a10b"), image: 'img-a' },
    { _id: new ObjectId("649e88ae9e6ef39cf8b3a10c"), image: 'img-b' }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```